# Add a table for all databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to add a table somewhere that all databases in that instance have access to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create "Main" database and access it with SQL queries from any other database in that SQL Server instance. It's just matter of user's privileges. Full syntax for `table_or_view_name` is `database.schema.object_name`.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable AS t
INNER JOIN Main.dbo.SharedTable AS s ON t.Id=s.Id
....
```

Chack documentation also - [FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

Comment: I don't want create linked server.I want a some thing like system views that accessible from all databses

Comment: This is not linked server. Linked server means that your "shared" database is on another SQL Server Instance. You don't have to configure anything additionally. Give it a try.

Comment: FYI also referencing a table using a linked server requires a 4 part name [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName].  To reference a table in another database on the same server  you only have to use a 3 part name. [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I added the second solution.**

**First solution** You could try using undocummented system procedure [sp_msforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb @command1=N'
USE ?;
IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''tempdb'',''msdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'')
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE CocoJamboTable (
        ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );
END
';

EXEC sp_msforeachdb @command1=N'
USE ?;
IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''tempdb'',''msdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'')
BEGIN
    SELECT  DB_NAME() AS DbName, name AS TableName, object_id FROM ?.sys.tables 
    WHERE   name=''CocoJamboTable''
END
';
```

**Second solution** You could generate a `T-SQL` script with all `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

PRINT 'BEGIN TRAN;'
/*
SELECT  
    'USE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(db.name) 
    + ';'
    + '
    CREATE TABLE CocoJamboTable (
        ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );'
    + CHAR(13)
*/
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN db.name IN ('master','model','tempdb','msdb','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB','ASPNETDB')
            THEN '-- Explicit skipping: '   + QUOTENAME(db.name)
        WHEN db.state <> 0 
            THEN '-- Implicit skipping (not online): '  + QUOTENAME(db.name)
        WHEN db.is_read_only=1
            THEN '-- Implicit skipping (read only): '   + QUOTENAME(db.name)                
        --WHEN other filter
        --  THEN '-- Implicit skipping (my filter): '   + QUOTENAME(db.name)                
        ELSE 
            'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(db.name) + '.dbo.CocoJamboTable (
                ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
            );'
        END 
        + CHAR(13)
FROM    sys.databases db
ORDER BY db.name;

PRINT 'ROLLBACK;'
PRINT '-- COMMIT;'
```

Then, press Ctrl+T (text results), F5 (execute), F6 (jump to text results panel), Ctrl+A (select all), Ctrl+C (copy), Ctrl+N (new window), Ctrl+V (paste - paste the script generated in previous step), F5 (execute).

Sample `T-SQL` script:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

CREATE TABLE [Comisioane].dbo.CocoJamboTable (
                ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
            );

-- Implicit skipping (read only): [Credite]

-- Explicit skipping: [master]

-- Explicit skipping: [model]

-- Explicit skipping: [msdb]

-- Explicit skipping: [ReportServer]

-- Explicit skipping: [ReportServerTempDB]

CREATE TABLE [SIMUR4].dbo.CocoJamboTable (
                ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
            );

ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT;
```

Comment: No, please stop recommending `sp_msforeachdb`. It's undocumented, unsupported, and completely broken ([and Microsoft will not fix it](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/752629/disable-sp-msforeachdb-by-default-or-fix-it)). See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thank you for your comment. I use sometimes this stored procedure for adhoc tasks. Yes, it is undocumented, I have written. It skips some databases: yes. This is the reason why I have written the second `sp_msforeachdb`. For others problems I use transactions: `BEGIN TRANSACTION; ...sp_for... ROLLBACK/COMMIT;`.  For `dbo.ForEachDB_MyWay`, will be nice to see a warning when skipping read only/not online databases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I added the second solution. Thank you.